# object HTMLInputElement error while entering a integer value to label in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

script code

```
intext = document.getElementById("intext");
totalin = document.getElementById("totalin");

function myFunction()
{
var x = document.getElementById("totalin");
x.innerHTML = intext.toString();
}
```

in the above code am getting object HTMLInputElement in the label with "totalin" id and textbox of number type with id = intext

i am new to javascript and i saw many other answers on similar problems but either cudn't understand the answers or they didn't worked .
thanks in advance for help.

part of Html code is as follows if required

```
<label for="text">input the income in numericals</label>
<input type="number" name="text" id="intext">
<a href="#" data-role="button" id="insub" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</a>
<label id="totalin" for="totalin">Label:</label>
```

i would really appreciate any help i am really in need of solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the `value` from the element:

```
x.innerHTML = intext.value;
```

You're also missing a quote close:

```
<input type="number" name="text id="intext">
                              ^ RIGHT THERE
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! the missing code was actually a mistake while posting the question not actually in the code which i have rectified and your other fix really works!!